# Heroku error while creating (in a Rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ubuntu, heroku

I'm a first time Heroku user, and this is my first Rails app. So this might sound a nube question. Sorry for that.

Anyway, when I try Heroku create or Heroku login from the project's root, this is the response I get. But when I do the same outside the project folder, everything works fine. The project is already a git repo.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

BTW, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
    heroku create
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2157:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x603d94 heroku-3.42.25> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1056:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:63:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/heroku-3.42.25/bin/heroku:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/heroku:23:in `load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: NEVER be sorry for trying. People may sneer, but you never get anywhere without trying

Comment: Thanks for the support @RichPeck :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`create command`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps#creating-a-named-app) expects a name.

To create an app with the name `my_app` call:

```
heroku create my_app
```

Comment: This is the answer, wish I got it

Comment: Hi @spickermann. Thanks for the answer. But I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me:

```
$ gem update heroku
```